# sharepoint 2013 mobile access with iphone - 401 unauthorized

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, mobile-view

I am having a really weird problem. I have dropped some html pages in my root site and when accessing them from any iPhone device i get 401 unauthorized. Now, i know about browser.compact file - i changed all isMobileDecvice to false on all the devices there. Yet i still get 401. Other mobile devices are ok.

thanks fro any help.

Answer (score 1):

after much research. i found this to be the only thing that helped:
in web.config of the site:
under: system.web

```
<browserCaps>
<result type="System.Web.Mobile.MobileCapabilities, System.Web.Mobile, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"/>
<filter>isMobileDevice=false</filter>
</browserCaps>
```